# How HttpNotFound is implemented and how to create similar methods for other errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.NET MVC, `Controller` class has only a limited set of methods to use to return something from an action.

There is a `HttpNotFoundResult HttpNotFound()` method, but no other methods for errors.

What's really inside `HttpNotFound()`? How to write a similar method for other error codes, like `401 Unauthorized` or `403 Forbidden` or `406 Not Acceptable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implemented this way:

```
public class HttpNotFoundResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
{
    public HttpNotFoundResult() : this(null)
    {
    }

    public HttpNotFoundResult(string statusDescription) : 
           base(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, statusDescription)
    {
    }
}
```

When executed, [HttpStatusCodeResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) simply sets status code and status description to `context.HttpContext.Response`. You can inherit from [HttpStatusCodeResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) class and create your own results. E.g.

```
public class HttpUnauthorizedResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
{
    public HttpUnauthorizedResult() : this(null)
    {
    }

    public HttpUnauthorizedResult(string statusDescription) : 
           base(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, statusDescription)
    {
    }
}
```